# .Net App Connection String Giving Null Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, microservices

I'm having an issue with my .Net app where I'm creating a microservice but for some reason my connection string isn't working properly.

Chrome Error I'm getting:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
  Unhandled exception rendering component: The argument namespaceConnectionString is null or white space. (Parameter 'namespaceConnectionString')
```

Debugging Null Value:

[image]

Project structure:

[image]

Appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureServiceBus": "Endpoint=sb://abduservicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=RandomChars="
  }
}
```

Connection Setting:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace SBSender.Services
{
    public class QueueService : IQueueService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        public QueueService(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }
        public async Task SendMessageAsync<T>(T serviceBusMessage, string queueName)
        {
            // Tested multiple connection string configuration 
                var queueClient = new QueueClient(_config.GetConnectionString("AzureServiceBus"), queueName);
                string messageBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(serviceBusMessage);
                Message message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));

                await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using SBSender;
using SBSender.Services;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddTransient<IQueueService, QueueService>();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Comment: Please include your code and any error message as text, not as images.

Comment: What happens if you pass a hard-coded string of the value in the configs?

Comment: @BrianParker I moved the appsettings file to the wwwroot folder but still getting the same error

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils you mean like _config.GetConnectionString("AzureServiceBus"); at the QueueService constructor ?

Comment: var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureServiceBus"); with the json file in the wwwroot folder.

Comment: If its WASM appsettings needs to be in the wwwroot if blazor server where you have it is fine. Your code looks like WASM ... `WebAssemblyHostBuilder`

Comment: @BrianParker it is a web assembly. I removed the _config.GetConnectionString("AzureServiceBus") and replaced it with the connection string value and I got a different error: System.Net.Sockets is not supported on this platform.

Comment: It seems like a compatibility issue.

Comment: I would host the WASM app then and use an API.

Comment: Yea I think that might be a better option, thanks for the assistance!

Comment: I mean passing the string value as opposed to getting it from the configs file to narrow it down. Sounds like you did that and found the underlying cause.

Answer (score 0):

You are using WASM. `appsettings.json` needs to be in the `wwwroot` folder.

```cs
public class QueueService : IQueueService
{
    public QueueService(IConfiguration config)
    {
        var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("AzureServiceBus");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the security implications of putting a config with potentially sensitive information in wwwroot? Does it differ with wsm as apposed to a "normal" frontend?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils be about the same as anything running on a browser....